# genstrings does not work when setting tableName parameter in NSLocalizedString

Tags: swift, localization, ios9, nslocalizedstring, genstrings

I am getting `Bad entry in file` error when using `genstrings` command line for every call to `NSLocalizedString` that uses `tableName` parameter

See the following example when trying to generate localized strings (from [Firefox-iOS](https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-ios))

```
find . -name *.swift | xargs genstrings -o en.lproj
```

> Bad entry in file ./StorageTests/TestSQLiteHistory.swift (line = 100): Argument is not a literal string.
>
> Bad entry in file ./StorageTests/TestSQLiteHistory.swift (line = 101): Argument is not a literal string.
>
> Bad entry in file ./StorageTests/TestSQLiteHistory.swift (line = 102): Argument is not a literal string.
>
> Bad entry in file ./StorageTests/TestSQLiteHistory.swift (line = 103): Argument is not a literal string. Argument is not a literal string.

Here is the code for these lines

```
let titleMobile = NSLocalizedString("Mobile Bookmarks", tableName: "Storage", comment: "The title of the folder that contains mobile bookmarks. This should match bookmarks.folder.mobile.label on Android.")
let titleMenu = NSLocalizedString("Bookmarks Menu", tableName: "Storage", comment: "The name of the folder that contains desktop bookmarks in the menu. This should match bookmarks.folder.menu.label on Android.")
let titleToolbar = NSLocalizedString("Bookmarks Toolbar", tableName: "Storage", comment: "The name of the folder that contains desktop bookmarks in the toolbar. This should match bookmarks.folder.toolbar.label on Android.")
let titleUnsorted = NSLocalizedString("Unsorted Bookmarks", tableName: "Storage", comment: "The name of the folder that contains unsorted desktop bookmarks. This should match bookmarks.folder.unfiled.label on Android.")
```

When I searched for a solution I found this [tool](https://github.com/KeepSafe/genstrings_swift) for generating and merging localized strings. It worked for this case, generated and merged the localized strings into `Localizable.strings` but in run time the app does not show the localized titles as it tries to load the localized strings form a file with the a name `Storage.strings` not from `Localizable.strings`

Is there is any solution to automatically generate these files instead of doing it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I need to translate the resources according to the latest procedure from apple

1. Export localization file `.xliff` using Xcode (select your Project in Xcode, then Editor -> Export for Localization)
2. Use a translation tool to translate all keys ([SwordFish](http://www.maxprograms.com/products/swordfish.html), [brightec online xliff editor](http://xliff.brightec.co.uk/form.php))
3. Import the translated file back into Xcode

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html